# JSP How to scale an image?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, image-scaling

Is there anyway to scale an image then display in jsp page? When retrieve and display the images, I want to show all photos in same size. is there any API can do it? I have searched from google, those I found was about scaling images byusing  tookit but can't works in web application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the builtin [Java 2D API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp) for this (basic Sun tutorial [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/)).

Basically, you need to create a [Servlet](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) which gets an `InputStream` of the original image in the `doGet()` method, passes it through the Java 2D API and then writes it to the `OutputStream` of the HTTP response. Then you just map this Servlet on a certain `url-pattern` in `web.xml`, e.g. `/thumbs/*` and call this Servlet in the `src` attribute of the HTML `<img>` element.

Here's a basic kickoff example (you still need to handle unexpected conditions yourself the way you want):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // First get image file name as request pathinfo (or parameter, whatever you want).
    String imageFilename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);

    // And get the thumbnail dimensions as request parameters as well.
    int thumbWidth = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("w"));
    int thumbHeight = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("h"));

    // Then get an InputStream of image from for example local disk file system.
    InputStream imageInput = new FileInputStream(new File("/images", imageFilename));

    // Now scale the image using Java 2D API to the desired thumb size.
    Image image = ImageIO.read(imageInput);
    BufferedImage thumb = new BufferedImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D graphics2D = thumb.createGraphics();
    graphics2D.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.WHITE); 
    graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
    graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight, null);

    // Write the image as JPG to the response along with correct content type.
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    ImageIO.write(thumb, "JPG", response.getOutputStream());
}
```

With the servlet mapped in `web.xml` as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>thumbServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.ThumbServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>thumbServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/thumbs/*</url-pattern>        
</servlet-mapping>
```

This can be used as follows:

```
<img src="thumbs/filename.jpg?w=100&h=100" width="100" height="100">
```

---

Note: no, this cannot be done with JSP alone since it's a view technology unsuitable for this task.

---

Note 2: this is a pretty expensive (CPU intensive) task, keep this in mind. You may want to consider to cache or pregenerate the thumbs beforehand yourself.

Comment: I did the same, Image border only displayed in the excel. Any idea?FYI Before i specified the w and h parameter the image was displaying but not with specified size.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: no, this cannot be done with JSP
>   alone since it's a view technology
>   unsuitable for this task.

Technically you can do it, but indeed it's not something that's advisable.

And yes, I'd cache the images for a long time, together with something to identify changes to the original, then recreate the resized image only if the original changes (or the cache expires, maybe a week after the image was last accessed).