# How to change the size of image with given new height and width using java?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, image-uploading, image-resizing

This is my demo.jsp page where i have two fields to give new height and width to change the uploaded image size with new one.could anybody tell me how to do this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>ImageSizeModification</title>
    <script>
        function ImageResizer() {
            console.log('called');
            var srcImg = document.getElementById("imgID").value;
            var newImg = new Image();
            newImg.src = srcImg;
            var height = newImg.height;
            var width = newImg.width;
            var newWidth = document.getElementById("widthID").value;
            var newHeight = document.getElementById("HeightID").value;
            console.log(newImg, srcImg, newWidth, newHeight, height, width);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        out.println("<table>");
        out.println("<tr><td><input type='file' id='imgID'></td></tr>");
        out.println("<tr><td>Enter new Width:</td><td><input type='text' id='widthID'></td></tr>");
        out.println("<tr><td>Enter new Height:</td><td><input type='text' id='HeightID'></td></tr>");
        out.println("<tr><td><input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='ImageResizer()'></td></tr>");
        out.println("</table>");
    %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("imgID").style.height =  parseInt(newWidth) ;
document.getElementById("imgID").style.width =  parseInt(newHeight) ;
```

add above two line before console log.

or using Jquery

```
$('#imgID').width(700); 
$('#imgID').height(700);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is to resize an image in the browser, so a smaller file goes up to your server. If that's so, this is not a Java/JSP question, but a Javascript one.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434458/image-resizing-client-side-with-javascript-before-upload-to-the-server) discusses how to do that using javascript libraries, and I think might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with jsp alone you need to create a servlet get the image through Inputstream  manipulate it through any image manipulation api and write it to response. [Imgscalr](http://java.dzone.com/articles/cropping-rotate-and-resizing) is an easy to use api. You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938698/jsp-how-to-scale-an-image) example and clarification